# Why "who" in Ubuntu from Microsoft Store in Windows 10 doesn't work?

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, who

I have a question, why when I write "who" in the Ubuntu terminal from Microsoft Store in Windows 10 show nothing instead of showing username, date and time.

```
mark@DESKTOP-UD9H17S:~$ who
```

and after enter I don't see anything

In normal ubuntu, I see the username, date, time, etc.

And how ubuntu from Microsoft Store works? It's like a virtual machine or something like that?
And to get to the files to this Ubuntu I must write \wsl$ and I see a folder with Ubuntu, but why I don't see a folder when my Ubuntu turned off? I only see when Ubuntu is running. What's happened with that files, I see that they still exist when I turn off and turn on Ubuntu, so where system keep them?

Comment: This may be relevant to the first part of your question: [/init does not create /var/run/utmp](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/573)

Comment: Try `strace $(type -p who)` to see.